# Open Street Map Routing using Ships and Trains

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, api

I wanne know if is there a way to use the Open Street Map API to know the distances of ships and getting the distance of two points.

Maybe there is a profile for it i have searched for Marine Navigation and OSMR but i didn't found anything.

And Also can you install the Open Street Map Server on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BRouter web client](http://brouter.de/brouter-web/) to route with ships on rivers.

Simply select "river"-profile in the Options section (top-left). 
BRouter uses OpenStreetMap data. [Here is an example](http://brouter.de/brouter-web/#zoom=12&lat=52.3895&lon=12.9927&layer=OpenStreetMap&lonlats=13.176727,52.455173%7C12.940865,52.385868&nogos=&profile=river&alternativeidx=0&format=geojson).